# findOne() not returning data in nestjs typeorm mongodb

Tags: mongodb, nestjs, typeorm

i'm using typeorm with mongodb on nestjs , findone() is not working , i tried findOne(where:{email:email}) , findOne({email:email}), findOne(email)

```
 async findUser(email: string): Promise<User> {
   return await this.userRepo.findOne({ email: email });
 }
```